# Encrypt with GPG using a key passed as CLI argument

Tags: command-line, encryption, gpg

I want to create a script that would automatically encrypt and push to GitHub into public repo some sensible files I don't want to expose (but do want to keep together with the whole project).

As a solution I decided to encrypt them with GPG. The issue is that I can't find any clues on how to encrypt a particular file with a passphrase passed as a CLI argument to a `gpg -c` command.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Near dupe http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60213/gpg-asks-for-password-even-with-passphrase but this answer is better focussed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use one of the `--passphrase-...` options, in batch mode:

- `--passphrase-fd` reads the passphrase from the given file descriptor

  ```
    echo mysuperpassphrase | gpg --batch -c --passphrase-fd 0 file
  ```
- `--passphrase-file` reads the passphrase from the given file

  ```
    echo mysuperpassphrase > passphrase
    gpg --batch -c --passphrase-file passphrase file
  ```
- `--passphrase` uses the given string

  ```
    gpg --batch -c --passphrase mysuperpassphrase file
  ```

These will all encrypt `file` (into `file.gpg`) using `mysuperpassphrase`.

With GPG 2.1 or later, you also need to set the PIN entry mode to “loopback”:

```
gpg --batch -c --pinentry-mode loopback --passphrase-file passphrase file
```

etc.

Decryption can be performed in a similar fashion, using `-d` instead of `-c`, and redirecting the output:

```
gpg --batch -d --passphrase-file passphrase file.gpg > file
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Follow-up question: where I can find some kind of man page where **all** command and options of gpg are listed? (as my ArchLinux man lists just a tiny bit and I found no --passphrase option on the web)

Comment: The [GPG site](https://gnupg.org) has manuals, *e.g.* [Invoking GPG](https://gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Invoking-GPG.html) (which lists all the options for GPG 2.1); the [Debian manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/1/gpg) is also available.

Comment: Could I apply this if I want to decript a file? like `gpg --batch -c --passphrase-file pas.txt --decrypt file.gpg`

Comment: @alper you need to drop the `-c` command, and specify where to write the output: `gpg --batch -d --passphrase-file pas.txt file.gpg > file`

Comment: I have also come up with this using (`--pinentry-mode loopback`):                                   `gpg --output file --pinentry-mode loopback --passphrase-file=pas.txt --decrypt file.gpg`, which also seems like working

Comment: Ah yes, that’s required since version 2.1, I’ll add that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the accepted answer but didn't work out.

I was on `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS`

Check my [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/631255/358653) which worked out for me