# GPG Sign + Encrypt a file with passphrase

Tags: gpg

I am developing a script that will sign and encrypt a file.

I have 2 problems:

1. While running the script it sometimes ask for a passphrase then after entering it manually in the next run it will not ask me again. Then after some time it will ask me again for passphrase. Is it just a session after I enter the passphrase manually that after some time the session will end and I need to enter it again? If so how can I automate this?

Command Used:

```
gpg --always-trust --compress-algo 1 --cipher-algo cast5 --armor \
    --recipient test@google.com --local-user localuser@google.com --passphrase "asdf2lkjh" \
    --output done_output.txt.gpg -se o113142.out
```

2. Before I can sign + encrypt a file I need to execute screen command. I am using `screen -m -d bash -c scriptname.sh`, but upon checking the list of screen, every time I'm running the command another detached screen is added. How can I run the script that automatically executes the screen and exit the screen after the script is done running.

I'm planning to run this via `crontab` and it needs to run without any manual entering of passphrase or killing the screen.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/330305/encrypt-with-gpg-using-a-key-passed-as-cli-argument. The first part of your question can be solved with: `gpg --batch --yes --passphrase ${ENC_KEY} -ac ${file}`. Just add all other options to sign. As of the second part - here I won't help you as have never used `screen` utility.

Comment: Hi ddnomad! thank you so much for your help! it is now working for me now, its not prompting me to enter the passphrase manually! thanks!!