# Is there any program to get the GPG password from the GUI

Tags: gui, gpg, zenity, pgp

I am working about a GUI PGP application with Zenity. GPG asks passphrase on terminal screen. But I want to enter passphrase from a GUI dialog box not in terminal (like `zenity --password`) I tried piping `gpg -c <file_name>` with Zenity command but not working. Is there any solution for this or another program feature? I know Kleopatra, GPA and seahorse by the way.

Thanks...

Comment: Which version of GPG are you using?

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60213/gpg-asks-for-password-even-with-passphrase -- somewhat different Q but several As are about piping the passphrase into `gpg`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks [dave_thompson_085](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/59699/dave-thompson-085). I tried `echo "123" | gpg --batch --yes --passphrase-fd 0 --cipher-algo AES256 -c $FILE` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still struggling:

You can change the `pinentry-mode` (`~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`) to `ask` and you'll always get the GUI prompt to enter the password (unless the passphrase is saved).

This is useful for various IDEs like Intellij.

Config file entry:

```
# your previous options
pinentry-mode ask
```