# gpg --passphrase-file doesn't work as root?

Tags: gpg

I'm trying to encrypt our backups using GnuPG as a pipe (reading from stdin and writing to stdout).  The passphrase is read from a file.  An example command:

```
echo "mysecret" | gpg --passphrase-file password.key --batch --symmetric --cipher-algo AES256 > test.gpg
```

When I run this as a regular user, it works fine. But if I run it as root, I get:

```
gpg: gpg-agent is not available in this session
gpg: can't query passphrase in batch mode
gpg: error creating passphrase: invalid passphrase
gpg: symmetric encryption of `[stdin]' failed: invalid passphrase
```

How can I get `--passphrase-file` working for root?

I cannot use `--passphrase-fd 0` as suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60213/gpg-asks-for-password-even-with-passphrase) because stdin is the data to be encrypted.  I'm using GPG 1.4.20 (from Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS)

Comment: If you're using `sudo` for running the command, can you verify that the environment variables required by GPG are set?

Comment: What environment variables does GPG need? I'm not using any keychains etc, just doing symmetric encryption.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround, which utilizes an additional file descriptor for input:

```
exec {FD}<password.key
echo "mysecret" | gpg --passphrase-fd ${FD} --batch --symmetric --cipher-algo AES256 > test.gpg
```

Comment: do you have to clean up the file descriptor?

Comment: `exec {FD}<&-` heres how to close it I think

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to build on the other answer, which involves writing the passphrase to the filesystem first. You can catch the output of a printf command as a file descriptor:

```
passphrase="topsecret"
exec {pw_fd}< <(printf "$passphrase")
echo "a total secret" | gpg --passphrase-fd ${pw_fd} --batch --symmetric --cipher-algo aes > test.gpg
exec {pw_fd}<&-
```

Then test:

```
gpg -d --passphrase -i test.gpg
gpg: AES.CFB encrypted data
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
a total secret
```