# How to avoid prompts for passphrase while clearsigning a file?

Tags: linux, gpg

I am using GPG Version 2.2.20 and whenever I run the following command while signing the release file, I am prompted for the passphrase.

```bsh
gpg  --default-key <my_email> --clearsign -o - Release > InRelease
```

I want to avoid getting prompts and pass the `passphrase` directly in the command. After reading a few answers for other questions, I tried these commands:

```
gpg  --default-key <my_email> --passphrase <my_passphrase> --clearsign -o - Release > InRelease
```

```
gpg  --default-key <my_email>  --batch --passphrase <my_passphrase> --clearsign -o - Release > InRelease
```

But the problem is still the same, it is prompting me for the passphrase instead of taking directly from the given command. How do I pass the passphrase correctly to the command?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gpg asks for password even with --passphrase](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60213/gpg-asks-for-password-even-with-passphrase)

Comment: @FelixJN I tried but none of the answers helped in my case.

Comment: @ShubhanshuSaxena look at the answer that received the bounty on that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For GnuPG version 2.1 and later you must include the option `--pinentry-mode loopback` in order for the `--passphrase` option to work.

Comment: That's maybe the part I was missing. Thanks a lot.